# Groovy List as Int number

Tags: groovy

I have the following Groovy code :

```
def number = "246" as List
def number1= number.subsequences() 
//outputs: [[6], [2, 6], [4, 6], [2], [2, 4, 6], [4], [2, 4]]
```

Now what i want is, each list in `number1` should be returned as `int`, say for example the second list in `number1` should be returned as `26`. What i have did was :

```
number1.each{ it }.collect() as int
```

Which is not working and throwing an error. Can this be done in any other ways?
Thanks in advance and correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need:

```
number1.collect { it.join() as int }
```

That will `join()` each of the numbers in the sub-lists into a `String`, then convert that `String` to an `int`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative that uses the spread operator instead of collect:

```
number1*.join()*.asType(Integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never used Groovy before but how about:

```
number1.collect{ it.join('') as int }
Result: [6, 26, 46, 2, 246, 4, 24]
```

Looks like a cool language.

Comment: havent used Groovy before, but still you got the answer.. Superb Stuff :D